# Chained queries for FHIR in AWS HealthLake

Tags: amazon-web-services, hl7-fhir

I have a FHIR structure that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "resourceType": "Organization",
    "id": "Clinic-10394",
    "identifier": [
      {
        "use": "official",
        "system": "http://example.org/clinic-identifiers",
        "value": "Clinic-10394"
      }
    ],
    "active": true,
    "type": [
      {
        "coding": [
          {
            "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/organization-type",
            "code": "prov",
            "display": "Healthcare Provider"
          }
        ],
        "text": "Healthcare Provider"
      }
    ],
    "name": "Olson-Edwards",
    "telecom": [
      {
        "system": "phone",
        "value": "995-784-8499"
      }
    ],
    "address": [
      {
        "line": ["049 Brown Lane"],
        "city": "Deniseport",
        "state": "ND",
        "postalCode": "97716",
        "country": "TH"
      }
    ],
    "partOf": {
      "reference": "Organization/HealthSystem-12345"
    }
  },
  {
    "resourceType": "Practitioner",
    "id": "1571",
    "text": {
      "status": "generated",
      "div": "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>Stephen Frazier</div>"
    },
    "identifier": [
      {
        "type": {
          "coding": [
            {
              "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0203",
              "code": "NPI"
            }
          ]
        },
        "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/sid/us-npi",
        "value": "776430790757"
      }
    ],
    "name": [
      {
        "use": "official",
        "family": "Frazier",
        "given": ["Stephen"],
        "prefix": ["Dr"]
      }
    ],
    "gender": "male",
    "telecom": [
      {
        "system": "phone",
        "value": "001-855-983-6124x7687",
        "use": "work"
      }
    ],
    "address": [
      {
        "use": "home",
        "line": ["572 Norton Motorway Suite 742\nPort Todd, SC 01619"]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "fullUrl": "urn:uuid:250542",
    "resource": {
      "resourceType": "PractitionerRole",
      "practitioner": {
        "reference": "Practitioner/1571",
        "display": "Dr. Stephen Frazier"
      },
      "organization": {
        "reference": "Organization/Clinic-10394",
        "display": "Olson-Edwards"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

This is not PHI data, it's a randomized one. I need to make a chained query in the AWS HealthLake, by searching for all organizations under a PractitionerRole using the NPI. However, inside the resource PractitionerRole, we only have the Practitioner ID reference. I know it's possible to do so: [AWS HealthLake - Chaining](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/healthlake/latest/devguide/search-parameters-advanced.html).

However, I could not find the right way to format my endpoint. I tried some, but without success. To me, this one looks close, but maybe I'm missing something here:

PractitionerRole?practitioner.identifier= 776430790757&_include=PractitionerRole:organization

Any ideas?